# firebase init command failing to execute

Tags: firebase, authentication, continuous-integration, firebase-tools

Can someone help me to solve this error  I cannot run firebase init command before running firebase deploy.

> Error: Authentication Error: Your credentials are no longer valid. Please run firebase login --reauth
>
> For CI servers and headless environments, generate a new token with firebase login:ci

Comment: If nothing works then change your internet. 
My issue resolved when my changed my network.

Answer (score 6):

if you are behind proxy invoke `set "NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0"`
as described  [here](http://softwareprojectmusings.blogspot.co.il/2017/05/deploying-to-firebase-from-behind-proxy.html)

Comment: Linux/macOS users should replace `set` with `export`.

Comment: Seem like this command only working on `cmd`, how can I do this with `powershell`?

Comment: While this didn't resolve my issue, it reminded me that `firebase` internally uses `node` (which I had firewalled - which was ultimately causing the auth failure) - thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work. Even running from cmd or powershell.

Answer (score 2):

Your credentials are not valid
All you need is to login again
Try the command `firebase login --reauth`

Answer (score 0):

For such Authentication Error from Firebase CLI.

Do the below steps:

```
 1. firebase logout
 2. firebase login
 3. Once the URL opens, go to Google account and remove access which was already given to firebase app distribution ["Remove Access"]
 4. Come back to the URL window and select Allow
 5. Should result in a successful login
```

Even after this repeatedly getting Firebase login CLI issue - suggest restart your system and do `firebase login` again

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this command

```
set "NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0"
```

and then re-run,

```
firebase login
```